# Can sympy determine if expression is positive?

Tags: python, sympy

Consider the following example:

```
import sympy
x = sympy.Symbol(x, real=True)
expr = sympy.sin(x) + 1
```

can Sympy somehow determine that `expr >= 0` is always true?

Comment: See the following issue in github: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/8533

Answer (score 5):

You could try solving the inequality for `x`:

```
>>> from sympy.solvers.inequalities import solve_univariate_inequality
>>> solve_univariate_inequality(expr >= 0, x)
And(-oo < x, x < oo)
```

So here SymPy tells you that the inequality holds true for any real number.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the assumption system to inquire about the attributes of an expression. There was a recent question about this [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sympy/WFtC3FoQdOc) wherein Nair gives some good references. But for your case, simply try

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var('x', real=True)
x
>>> (sin(x)+1).is_positive
>>> (sin(x)+1).is_nonnegative
```

The result will either be True, False or (in this case) None. `None` means either that the result is unknown or that the determination has not been implemented. In this case, the result for nonnegative should have been True. Improving the assumptions system is an active work with SymPy.